# Change git account root folder, i.e mine is github.com/caverdude to github.com/somethingelse

Tags: github, url

I started my github account and I used a chat room handle for the root folder so that when you go to github.com/caverdude it's my stuff. I'd now like to change this caverdude to something more professional. Like my business name, or my name or something.

A google search turned up something totally different like changing the root folder in a repository.

Answer (score 0):

Man, I've been there.  I believe once you [change your github username](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/changing-your-github-username#changing-your-username) it will effectively change your repo root url.

fyi - I believe they will create redirects from the old urls to the new ones but only so long as another caverdude account isn't created.  If another user named caverdude comes along at a later time the redirects from the old name to your new name will stop working.

Recently on a project I followed but hadn't really bookmarked or forked changed their name to something mysterious and it was a brief mystery as their old profile showed Github's custom 404/ not found.  Eventually I tracked it back to their new, not-very-obvious name.  All this to say, the whole "old redirects to new account" seems a might bit tenuous.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your username in your account settings:

Click profile picture
Settings
Account
Change username

This will change your root folder on your profile page to the new username, and any links with your old name will show 404 error. So, you’ll need to update your links, but your repos will be updated with your new username. Here is the [article from GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/changing-your-github-username) which gives you the steps and what happens after changing usernames :). Hope that helps, take care!